# using-declaration for overloaded inherited function template leads to "ambiguous call to overloaded function"

Tags: c++, c++03, function-templates

I have a base class template `C` that implements multiple overloads of a function `c()`, of which one is a function template, and a sub class `D` that inherits from C and re-implements the function template.
`D::c()` causes all overloads of `C::c()` to be hidden in `D`. As I want the overloads that are not re-implemented by `D` to not be hidden, `D` makes them available via `using C<D>::c`;

This works fine if all overloads of `c()` are non templated functions: The base implementations are available to users of D for overloads that `D` does not re-implement, but for overloads that `D` re-implements, the implementation from `C` becomes unavailable to users of D and the implementation from `D` is used instead.

However if the re-implemented function is a function template, then the same approach leads to a compiler error in MSVC.

```
"ambiguous call to overloaded function
could be 'void D::c<int>(FT)
or       'void C::c<int>(FT)'"
```

Apparently with templates the `C` implementation stays available to `D` users and conflicts with the re-implementation in `D`.

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
    void c(void){}
    template<typename FT> void c(FT param){}
};

class D : public C<D>
{
public:
    using C<D>::c;
    template<typename FT> void c(FT param){}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.c<int>(1);
}
```

clang and G++ both compile this code just fine, while MSVC 11, 12, 14 and 15 all fail to compile it.
A simplified version of the code in which `C` is not a template, but an ordinary class, still fails to compile in MSVC 11 and 12, but compiles fine in MSVC 14 and 15.

With the usual approach not working is there any better approach in C++03 for re-implementing an inherited overloaded function template than to abstain from using `using C<D>::c` and instead adding re-implementations for all overloads, of which some do nothing more than only calling their base implementation?

Note:
I can't use C++11 or any newer standards.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question you linked. Your use case in a conforming C++ implementation should not be ambiguous. You declare a member function template in `D` with the exact same signature as in `C`. The linked question uses two member function template with **different signatures**.

Comment: Can you also please specify the exact MSVC version you are using? The earliest one I used (https://godbolt.org/z/fFWZpW) accepts you code just fine.

Comment: @StoryTeller:
The oldest VC version that the code base still supports is VC11 (Visual Studio 2012), so this is what is used for development, although builds for VC12 (VS 2013), VC14 (VS 2015) and VC15 (VS 2017) are also provided with each release.
However to check if this might be an issue that is only existing in older versions I have also tested this code with VC15 and that version still gives me the same error. Interestingly the link to godbolt that you provided states that it would use VC19, when VC16 (from VS2019, which was released last month) is the newest major version of VC.

Comment: The godbolt option I chose was grouped under MSVC 2015 in the combo box. Any way, this is the oldest version I found, and I don't use VC++ in day to day operation. Ultimately, it's not a language problem. Clang and G++ both accept it as C++03, and I made a point to again use old versions in C++03 mode. (https://godbolt.org/z/gH19pN).

Comment: @StoryTeller:
Apparently I was wrong in my previous comment.
VC11 and VC12 fail to compile the original repro case, but VC14 and VC15 compile it just fine.
However they fail to compile a modified CRTP version of that repro case that is closer to our real-world case, and in which `C` is a class template and `D` inherits from `C<D>`. GCC and clang successfully build the CRTP version.
https://godbolt.org/z/vkLHvz